# Making v-model:value lazy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a simple Vue component, which comes from a 3rd party package.

The component is a text editor, and I have to provide it with a value for it to render correctly.

```html
<SomeComponent v-model:value="text" />

<script setup>
const props = {
    records: {
        type: Object,
    },
}
const text = computed(() => props.records.first())
</script>
```

Now, I want to update my database everytime the `text` property is changed.

```js
watch(text, () => {
    //Post to database...
})
```

I don't, however, want to update the database on every keystroke - hence, I want to make the `v-model` lazy. This I am trying to do like this:

```js
<SomeComponent v-model:value.lazy="text" />
```

However, this doesn't work. The code inside my `watch` method is being fired on every keystroke.

Comment: What is `value` in `v-model:value.lazy="text"`?

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not need to use `v-model:value="text"`, just `v-model="text"` is enough.
2. If you wanted the input to be lazy, without any extra functionality (like posting to DB on every change) then `v-model.lazy="text"` would be enough.
3. When using `watch`, it doesn't matter whether your input is updated lazily or instantly. The watcher watches for each and every change, i.e: every keystroke in the case of an input.

---

So if you wish to make it lazy and make a call to DB on every change, then you need to this:

```html
<SomeComponent :value="text" @change="onChange">\

<script setup>
   const onChange = (event) => {
     text.value = event.target.value;
     // post to DB
   }
</script>
```

---

If this doesn't work, then the suspect is the 3rd party package. In which case I suggest you look at the package's documentation and see if they provide a prop for the text editor to be lazy.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [the documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#form-input-bindings), `v-model` is just some sugar syntax.

So that those are the same

```html
<input v-model="text">

<input :value="text" @input="event => text = event.target.value">
```

If you want to have your component updated on the change event, you could then use something like this

```html
<SomeComponent :value="text" @change="event => text = event.target.value" />
```

Or this one rather

```html
<SomeComponent v-model.lazy="text" /> <!-- text is the getter and the setter here -->
```

As shown in the documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#lazy

---

If you want something even more advanced, you could look into debouncing your inputs (more work but it's kinda more *clever* into handling when to update the state).

Comment: If I don't add `:value` to `v-model:value, then I get the following error: `[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "value" 
  at <Anonymous class="text-base" modelValue=undefined onUpdate:modelValue=fn`

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd party plugin did not allow me to omit the `v-model:value` property, so I ended up using lodash' [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) method instead:

```html
<SomeComponent v-model:value.lazy="text" />
```

```js
watch(text, _.debounce(function () {
    //Post to database...
}, 500));
```